# UI interactions in Gamescene

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel

I created UI Buttons and labels in my storyboard and have interacted with them from GameViewController but I wanted to know how to interact with them from Gamescene.

Comment: You can't interact with them from the game scene. It has to be from the viewcontroller